# Привести функции в более читаемый вид

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Написал перевод в польскую нотацию, тут только часть кода с конкретными функциями. Глобальные чисто, чтобы побыстрее рабочую версию части кода сделать (в основном коде это приватные переменные класса).

```cpp
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stack>

std::vector<std::string> polish_;
std::vector<std::string> vector_of_str_ = {"2","+","3","/","4"};
bool error_ = false;

bool MaxNumber(std::string &str) {
  double max_number = 900719925474099;
  bool return_value = false;
  if (str[0] >= '0' && str[0] <='9' && stod(str) > max_number) {
    return_value = true;
  }
  return return_value;
}

void ComparePriority(std::stack<std::pair<std::string, int>> &symbol_stack, std::string &current_symbol,
                     const std::string &operation, int priority, int &check_if_pushed) {
  if (!current_symbol.compare(operation) && check_if_pushed == false) {
    while (symbol_stack.size() > 0 && symbol_stack.top().second >= priority) {
      polish_.push_back(symbol_stack.top().first);
      symbol_stack.pop();
    }
    check_if_pushed = true;
    symbol_stack.push({current_symbol, priority});
  } else {
    check_if_pushed = false;
  }
}


void ConvertToPolishNotation() {
  std::map<std::string, int> oper_with_prior = {{"-",1},    {"+",1},    {"*",2},    {"/",2},   {"^",4},  {"~",3},
                                                      {"cos",5},  {"sin",5},  {"tg",5},   {"abs",5}, {"ln",5}, {"sqrt",5},
                                                      {"acos",5}, {"asin",5}, {"atan",5}, {"log",5}, {"%",2}};
  int str_len = vector_of_str_.size();
  int i = 0, left_brackets_counter = 0, check_if_pushed = false;
  std::stack<std::pair<std::string, int>> symbol_stack;
  while (str_len && error_ == false) {
    if (MaxNumber(vector_of_str_[i])) {
      error_ = true;
    } else {
      --str_len;
      if (vector_of_str_[i].compare("(") == 0) {
        symbol_stack.push({vector_of_str_[i], 0});
        ++left_brackets_counter;
        check_if_pushed = true;
      } else if (vector_of_str_[i].compare(")") == 0) {
        if (left_brackets_counter == 0) {
          error_ = true;
        } else {
          while (symbol_stack.top().first.compare("(") != 0) {
            polish_.push_back(symbol_stack.top().first);
            symbol_stack.pop();
          }
          check_if_pushed = true;
          symbol_stack.pop();
        }
        --left_brackets_counter;
      } else {
          for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = oper_with_prior.begin(); it != oper_with_prior.end() && check_if_pushed != true; ++it) {
              ComparePriority(symbol_stack, vector_of_str_[i], it->first, it->second, check_if_pushed);
          }
      }
      if (error_ == false) {
        if (check_if_pushed == false) {
          polish_.push_back(vector_of_str_[i]);
        }
        check_if_pushed = false;
        ++i;
      }
    }
  }
  while (symbol_stack.size() != 0) {
    polish_.push_back(symbol_stack.top().first);
    symbol_stack.pop();
  }
  if (left_brackets_counter > 0) {
    error_ = true;
  }
}


int main() {
    
    ConvertToPolishNotation();
    for (int i = 0; i < polish_.size(); i++) {
        std::cout<<polish_[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Функции `MaxNumber, ComparePriority, ConvertToPolishNotation`. Можно их как-то причесать, чтобы стало более понятно и читабельно? Мне то самому вроде и все понятно и читабельно, но вот препод сказал, что не очень и надо что-то исправить в этом плане.

Comment: Опишите словами что делает функция `ComparePriority`.

Comment: Сравнивает приоритеты операций вычисления, если у текущего символа строки приоритет больше(или меньше, тут я уже подзабыл, как оно работает в польской) того, что на вершине стека, который хранит пары операция+приоритет. В цикле пока выполняется условие с вершины стека достаем строку операции вычисления и заносим её в строку польской нотации, а из стека элемент удаляем. Когда условие перестало выполняться, заносит в стек текущую операцию. Как-то так...

Comment: Переработайте код так чтобы каждая функция делала одну вещь,  суть которой можно отразить в её коротком наименовании. Сейчас ни одна функция не делает то что на ней написано.

Comment: Ну ConvertToPolishNotation же дает вектор строк, представляющий собой как бы одну строку в польской нотации? Как тогда правильно назвать эту функцию?

Comment: Функция ComparePriority всего на 12 строк. Должна одновременно удалять из стека последний элемент и добавлять его же в "польскую" строку. С условием сравнивания приоритетов. Даже не представляю, как это разделить можно...

Comment: Принципиальная ошибка, порождающая столь громоздкий код в том, что вы рассматриваете скобки (`(` и `)`) как отдельные синтаксические сущности. Если их рассматривать как **операции (со своим приоритетом)**, то структура алгоритма  существенно упростится. При таком подходе у вас будет 2 вложенных цикла -- 1) взять входную лексему 2) (вложенный цикл) пока приоритет лексемы больше приоритета вершины стека вынимать лексемы из стека и добавлять к выходной последовательности (тут вложенные скобки будут уничтожаться, скобку извлеченную из стека на выход отправлять не надо) 3) занести лексему в стек

Comment: И не надо использовать столь изощренные крестовые структуры данных (все эти шаблоны совсем ни к чему (слишком много букв)). Помните о KISS-принципе

Comment: Что за крестовые структуры данных? Даже не гуглится)

Comment: [`int i = 0, left_brackets_counter = 0, check_if_pushed = false;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJCpA.jpg)

Comment: @ChetNePolichaetsa, кресты -- это С++ (надеюсь, многое сразу прояснится...)